# Interactive less search with wildcards

Tags: regular-expression, less

I'm using `less` to view a large file and I want to search for a pattern with wildcards — e.g., " x 1??" where `?` is any character.  Does `less` support that, and if so how would I do that interactively?

Comment: `less` search is regex so `x 1..`

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_less.htm

Comment: Not quite a duplicate: I wasn't able to determine through previous searching that less search uses regex, so @jordanm has the answer.  Could he post it as such?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The search in `less` uses regular expressions. To accomplish the search you are looking for, simply replace the shell wildcard `?` with `.`.

```
/x 1..
```